# How to remove the duplicate words between the line using Awk

Tags: awk

how to remove duplicate words from the below given pattern in a file

file pattern :

```
/bin/sh --promote-module test-c_abc_toy_debug_v2_3_1-1.0.140603101548 --repo-id Test-rhel-appdev-sun-puppet
/bin/sh --promote-module test-c_def_debug_v2_3_1-1.0.140603101548 --repo-id Test-rhel-appdev-sol-puppet 
/bin/sh --promote-rpm c-test-hell-debug-231-2.3.1-140603101548.noarch.rpm,c-test-hell-debug-231-2.3.1-140603101548.noarch.rpm --repo-id Test-rhel-6-server-x86_64-appdev-sun 
/bin/sh --promote-rpm c-test-heaven-debug-2.3.1-140603101548.noarch.rpm,c-test-heaven-debug-2.3.1-140603101548.noarch.rpm,c-test-heaven-prod-2.3.1-140603101548.noarch.rpm --repo-id Test-rhel-6-server-x86_64-appdev-sol
```

Desired output :

```
/bin/sh --promote-module test-c_abc_toy_debug_v2_3_1-1.0.140603101548 --repo-id Test-rhel-appdev-sun-puppet
/bin/sh --promote-module test-c_def_debug_v2_3_1-1.0.140603101548 --repo-id Test-rhel-appdev-sol-puppet 
/bin/sh --promote-rpm c-test-hell-debug-231-2.3.1-140603101548.noarch.rpm --repo-id Test-rhel-6-server-x86_64-appdev-sun 
/bin/sh --promote-rpm c-test-heaven-debug-2.3.1-140603101548.noarch.rpm,c-test-heaven-prod-2.3.1-140603101548.noarch.rpm --repo-id Test-rhel-6-server-x86_64-appdev-sol
```

Please note:

- there can be N number of lines in the file
- there can be N number of duplicates between the lines

Comment: can you highlight the difference? Too much text to skim through... May I suggest a **minimal** example :-)

Comment: I opened the input and output in my vimdiff, I saw the diff, but don't know the rule of processing....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your data only have duplicate words at third column(when FS=' '). If not, this will be wrong.
The script below works with GNU awk.

```
cat your_data_file | awk '
{
    system("echo " $3 "| tr , \"\\n\" | sort | uniq | paste -sd, > tmp ")
    "cat tmp" | getline $3
    close("cat tmp")
    system("rm tmp")
    print $0
}
'
```